# Oracle SQL if else String

Tags: sql, oracle, case

i have a table that contains a list of names called `queues`. All of these queues have some data (`integer`) now in some cases i want two of the queues to be as one and i have therefore tried to create the following statement:

```
    (case when QUEUE in ('Erhverv', 'ErhvervOverflow') then 'Erhverv' 
          ELSIF WHEN QUEUE in ('Hotline', 'TekniskHotline') then Hotline+TekniskHotline' 
          else QUEUE end
    ) as QUEUE,
```

However it does not seem to work.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**FULL SQL STATEMENT**

```
    SELECT   TRUNC(TIDSPUNKT) AS PERIOD,
         (CASE queue WHEN queue in ('Erhverv', 'ErhvervOverflow')
 then 'Erhverv' WHEN queue in ('Hotline', 'TekniskHotline') 
then 'Hotline+TekniskHotline' ELSE QUEUE end) as QUEUE,
         SUM(ANTAL_KALD) AS CALLS,
         SUM(INTERN_KALD) AS INTERNAL_CALLS
FROM     KS_DRIFT.PERO_NKM_KØ_OVERSIGT
WHERE    TIDSPUNKT >= '2013-06-18'
AND      TIDSPUNKT <= '2013-07-03'
GROUP BY TRUNC(TIDSPUNKT), QUEUE
```

Comment: "It does not seem to work" is not very helpful.  Please tell us what actually happens, including any error messages you get.  Clearly in this case you have some syntax errors but we shouldn't have to guess.  Remember, only *you* can see your screen: we only know what you tell us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELSIF is for branching IF statements not CASE statements.  Just use WHEN:

```
(case 
     when QUEUE in ('Erhverv', 'ErhvervOverflow') then 'Erhverv' 
     when QUEUE in ('Hotline', 'TekniskHotline') then 'Hotline+TekniskHotline' 
     -------------------------------------------------^ missing quote
     else QUEUE end
) as QUEUE,
```

Also, you have a missing quote in the second clause which certainly won't help your code to compile.

Regarding your update, [as the documentation shows](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/expressions004.htm#sthref1848), CASE has two different syntaxes. Use either the simple CASE syntax ...

```
case queue 
    when 'ErhvervOverflow' then 'Erhverv'
    when 'Hotline' then 'Hotline+TekniskHotline' 
    when 'TekniskHotline' then 'Hotline+TekniskHotline' 
    else queue
end case
```

... or the searched syntax ...

```
case 
    when queue  in ( 'ErhvervOverflow', 'Erhverv' ) then 'Erhverv'
    when queue  in ('Hotline' , 'TekniskHotline' ) then 'Hotline+TekniskHotline' 
    else queue
end case
```

Your error is cause by the attempt to use both syntaxes simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(CASE queue
WHEN queue in ('Erhverv', 'ErhvervOverflow') then 'Erhverv'
WHEN queue in ('Hotline', 'TekniskHotline') then 'Hotline+TekniskHotline'
ELSE QUEUE 
end) as QUEUE
```

Comment: Now im getting missing keyword ive updated my post giving the full statement i have so far

Comment: @MarcRasmussen: I really can't find any error with your updated query. please show your error message.

Comment: @sarwar026 - trying running your syntax and see what happens.